# Error con sintaxis de build en Docker

Tags: linux, docker

Estoy creando una imagen a partir de un contenedor en Docker que corre sobre una maquina virtual en Linux, pero me da este error: "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.

```
sudo docker build -t ubuntu_original:ubuntu_version2
```

Quisiera saber cual es la correcta forma de plantearlo y tambien si ubuntu_original seria el nombre del contenedor o de la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

*Nuh uh, nonono*. Ese comando no es pa eso. `docker build` crea una imagen a partir de un archivo de configuración (de un Dockerfile). No sé de dónde salió ese invento ;)

Para usar un contenedor en ejecución tienes que:

- Revisar con `docker ps -a` para ver cuál es el valor en la columna `NAMES` del contenedor que quieres usar. No es el nombre de la imagen porque estamso mirando **contenedores**.
- Usar `docker commit nombre_contenedor ubuntu_nuevo:0.1` para guardar el estado actual del contenedor **como una nueva imagen** con ese nombre. Te va a salir un hash de esa operación, algo como

```
sha256:0c17f0798823c7febc5a67d5432b48f525320d671beb2e6f04303f3da2f10432
```

- Haces `docker images -a` y verás una nueva imagen con el nombre que elegiste

```
~ docker images -a
REPOSITORY                       TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED              SIZE
ubuntu_nuevo                           0.1    0c17f0798823   About a minute ago   23.4MB
```

Ya ahí puedes elegir qué hacer con contenedor e imagen, por separado.

Comment: Muchas gracias... bueno si tienes razon ya habia replicado una imagen docker con commit y pues crei que build haria algo similar jejej

Comment: @ELKI_PARIONA si te sirvió la respuesta y resolvió tu problema (no antes), recuerda marcarla como aceptada. Siempre acude a la documentación en vez de suponer y morir en el intento ;)

Answer (score 0):

Debe agregar un punto, lo que significa usar Dockerfile en el directorio local.

```
sudo docker build -t ubuntu_original:ubuntu_version2 .
```

ubuntu_original ---> Nombre de imagen cuál tendrá creado

ubuntu_version2 ----> Tag, seria como la versión de imagen